# List of Sites and Subsites

Tags: sharepoint-server

How do I get a list of sites and subsites under each Web Application in MOSS 2007 and SharePoint 2010?

Answer (score 1):

From 2007 you'd probably want to use stsadm:

```
stsadm -o enumsites
```

For 2010 and above, Powershell is easiest:

```
Get-SPWebApplication -Limit All | Get-SPSite | Get-SPWeb | Format-Table -Property Title, URL
```

Answer (score 1):

You can run the below powershell to get the list of all sites and subsites in every webapplication.

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint") > $null 
$siteUrl = Read-Host "Enter Site URL" 
$rootSite = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite($siteUrl)
$spWebApp = $rootSite.WebApplication
$count = 0
           write-host "Site Collections" 
           write-host "" 
    foreach ($site in $spWebApp.Sites) { 
        $count++
        write-host "Site Collections URL --> -->" $site.URL 
           write-host "" 
           write-host "SubSites" 
           write-host "" 
    foreach ($web in $site.AllWebs) { 
        $count++
        write-host "SubSite URL --> --> -->" $web.URL  
        write-host ""
    }  
}
write-host "Total Count :" $count
```

http://jk-point.blogspot.com/2012/02/powershell-script-to-list-all.html

let say you web application http://webapplication

```
http://webapplication [is a root site collection]

http://webapplication/subsite1
http://webapplication/subsite1/subsite1.1
http://webapplication/subsite1/subsite1.1/subsite1.2

http://webapplication/subsite2
http://webapplication/subsite2/subsite2.1
```